# Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Extra content at the end of the document in http://widget.stagram.com/rss/n

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, rss, instagram

From last two week I'm getting following php warning message

> Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Extra content at the end of the document
>   in http://widget.stagram.com/rss/n/zee/, line: 10 in
>   /home//public_html/wp-content/themes//inc/social-instagram.php
>   on line 22

where I'm trying to parse this link in the warning message

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);
```

when I browse the link in web browser http://widget.stagram.com/rss/tag/zee/ the xml seems to be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use curl and add the option `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`. That's why it's working on the browser, and not by simple `file_get_contents` or `->load`. Consider this example:

```
$url = ('http://widget.stagram.com/rss/tag/zee/');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/lQMr3O)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the following solution worked without the need for CURL:

```
libxml_set_streams_context(
    stream_context_create(
        array(
            'http' => array(
                'user_agent' => 'php'            
            )
        )
    )
);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load($xml);
```

The extra content error went away and all the feeds I pushed through worked fine.

Big thanks to [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) for answering another question with this answer that led me to try it for this problem.